# Image skewness& kurtosis in python

Tags: python, image

Is there a python package that will provide me a way to clacluate Skewness and Kurtosis of an image?. Any example will be great.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By image do you mean you have a set of points ? What problem do you have to calculate these descriptors ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am assuming that you have an image that shows some kind of peak, and you are interesting in getting the Skewness and Kurtosis (and probably the standard deviation and centroid) of that peak in both the x and y directions.

I was wondering about this as well. Curiously, I did not find this implemented into any of the python image analysis packages. OpenCV has a [moments function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments), and we should be able to get the skewness from these, but the moments only go to 3rd order, and we need 4th order to get kurtosis.

To make things easier and faster, I think that taking the projection of the image in the x and y directions and finding the statistics from these projections is mathematically equivalent to finding the statistics using the full image. In the following code, I use both methods and show that they are the same for this smooth example. Using a real, noisy image, I found that the two methods also provide the same result, but only if you manually cast the image data to float64 (it imported as float 32, and "numerical stuff" caused the results to be slightly different.

Below is an example. You should be able to cut and paste the "image_statistics()" function into your own code. Hopefully it works for someone! :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax4 = plt.subplot(224)

#Make some sample data as a sum of two elliptical gaussians:
x = range(200)
y = range(200)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def twoD_gaussian(X,Y,A=1,xo=100,yo=100,sx=20,sy=10):
    return A*np.exp(-(X-xo)**2/(2.*sx**2)-(Y-yo)**2/(2.*sy**2))

Z = twoD_gaussian(X,Y) + twoD_gaussian(X,Y,A=0.4,yo=75)

ax2.imshow(Z) #plot it

#calculate projections along the x and y axes for the plots
yp = np.sum(Z,axis=1)
xp = np.sum(Z,axis=0)

ax1.plot(yp,np.linspace(0,len(yp),len(yp)))
ax4.plot(np.linspace(0,len(xp),len(xp)),xp)

#Here is the business:
def image_statistics(Z):
    #Input: Z, a 2D array, hopefully containing some sort of peak
    #Output: cx,cy,sx,sy,skx,sky,kx,ky
    #cx and cy are the coordinates of the centroid
    #sx and sy are the stardard deviation in the x and y directions
    #skx and sky are the skewness in the x and y directions
    #kx and ky are the Kurtosis in the x and y directions
    #Note: this is not the excess kurtosis. For a normal distribution
    #you expect the kurtosis will be 3.0. Just subtract 3 to get the
    #excess kurtosis.
    import numpy as np

    h,w = np.shape(Z)

    x = range(w)
    y = range(h)


    #calculate projections along the x and y axes
    yp = np.sum(Z,axis=1)
    xp = np.sum(Z,axis=0)

    #centroid
    cx = np.sum(x*xp)/np.sum(xp)
    cy = np.sum(y*yp)/np.sum(yp)

    #standard deviation
    x2 = (x-cx)**2
    y2 = (y-cy)**2

    sx = np.sqrt( np.sum(x2*xp)/np.sum(xp) )
    sy = np.sqrt( np.sum(y2*yp)/np.sum(yp) )

    #skewness
    x3 = (x-cx)**3
    y3 = (y-cy)**3

    skx = np.sum(xp*x3)/(np.sum(xp) * sx**3)
    sky = np.sum(yp*y3)/(np.sum(yp) * sy**3)

    #Kurtosis
    x4 = (x-cx)**4
    y4 = (y-cy)**4
    kx = np.sum(xp*x4)/(np.sum(xp) * sx**4)
    ky = np.sum(yp*y4)/(np.sum(yp) * sy**4)


    return cx,cy,sx,sy,skx,sky,kx,ky

#We can check that the result is the same if we use the full 2D data array
def image_statistics_2D(Z):
    h,w = np.shape(Z)

    x = range(w)
    y = range(h)

    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    #Centroid (mean)
    cx = np.sum(Z*X)/np.sum(Z)
    cy = np.sum(Z*Y)/np.sum(Z)

    ###Standard deviation
    x2 = (range(w) - cx)**2
    y2 = (range(h) - cy)**2

    X2,Y2 = np.meshgrid(x2,y2)

    #Find the variance
    vx = np.sum(Z*X2)/np.sum(Z)
    vy = np.sum(Z*Y2)/np.sum(Z)

    #SD is the sqrt of the variance
    sx,sy = np.sqrt(vx),np.sqrt(vy)

    ###Skewness
    x3 = (range(w) - cx)**3
    y3 = (range(h) - cy)**3

    X3,Y3 = np.meshgrid(x3,y3)

    #Find the thid central moment
    m3x = np.sum(Z*X3)/np.sum(Z)
    m3y = np.sum(Z*Y3)/np.sum(Z)

    #Skewness is the third central moment divided by SD cubed
    skx = m3x/sx**3
    sky = m3y/sy**3

    ###Kurtosis
    x4 = (range(w) - cx)**4
    y4 = (range(h) - cy)**4

    X4,Y4 = np.meshgrid(x4,y4)

    #Find the fourth central moment
    m4x = np.sum(Z*X4)/np.sum(Z)
    m4y = np.sum(Z*Y4)/np.sum(Z)

    #Kurtosis is the fourth central moment divided by SD to the fourth power
    kx = m4x/sx**4
    ky = m4y/sy**4

    return cx,cy,sx,sy,skx,sky,kx,ky


#Calculate the image statistics using the projection method
stats_pr = image_statistics(Z)

#Confirm that they are the same by using a 2D calculation
stats_2d = image_statistics_2D(Z)

names = ('Centroid x','Centroid y','StdDev x','StdDev y','Skewness x','Skewness y','Kurtosis x','Kurtosis y')

print 'Statistis\t1D\t2D'
for name,i1,i2 in zip(names, stats_2d,stats_pr):
    print '%s \t%.2f \t%.2f'%(name, i1,i2)

plt.show()
```

Screen shot of output, just for fun:

[image: screen shot of output]

One more thing: depending on exactly what you are doing with the images, you might consider using [ImageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/) for your image analysis – but beware! The [moments plugin](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/moments.html) will let you calculate the skewness, kurtosis, etc. ImageJ does have a "skewness" and "kurtosis" in Analyze>>Set Measurements menu, but I think that this actually finds the skewness and kurtosis of the intensity histogram (I was fooled for a minute).

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the age of this post but was wondering if you might be able to explain what the difference between an absolute value of Kurtosis and Skewness and the X/Y directions you refer to. In your example, you calculate Kurtosis in the X and Y directions, but in scipy's kurtosis function it gives a single value (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html). Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: scipy.stats.kurtosis only finds the kurtosis along one axis. You could get both by using
```kur_x = scipy.stats.kurtosis(a, axis=1)```
```kur_y = scipy.stats.kurtosis(a, axis=0)```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! To give some context I'm trying to implement this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4488699 (An Automated Technique for Image Noise Identification Using a Simple Pattern Classification Approach), which uses Skewness and Kurtosis as values to differentiate types of noise in an image.
For this paper, there is an absolute (single) value of Kurtosis and Skewness. In this case, what do you think they're doing?
My gut feeling is that they're only finding the kurtosis along one axis because noise in an image won't differ in X/Y directions.

Comment: For those viewing at home, here is a non-paywall link to that paper: https://www.slideshare.net/YixinChen13/an-automated-technique-for-image-noise-identification-using-a-simple-pattern-classification-approach-153988925  I think that their are basically making a histogram of the intensities (x-axis = gray value, y-axis = number of pixels with that value). Then they are looking at the skewness and kurtosis of this plot. This question (and answer) deal with the skewness and kurtosis of the actual image (i.e., we take a projection where x-axis = x position, y-axis = (sum of pixels in this column))

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference. Appreciate it :)