# Get a blobs Skewness by inspecting 3rd Order Moment?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I've been reading up on Image Moments and it looks like they are very useful for efficiently describing a blob. Apparently, the 3rd order moment represents/can tell me about a blob's skewness (is this correct?).

- How can I get the 3rd order moment in OpenCV? Do you have a calculation/formula you can point me to?

  Moments m = moments(contour, false);
  // Are any of these the 3rd order moment?
  m.m03;
  m.mu03;
  m.nu03;

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [OpenCV docs for `moments()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments):

> Calculates all of the moments *up to the third order* of a polygon or rasterized shape.

So yes, `moments()` does return what you're after.

The three quantities you mention, `m03`, `mu03`, `nu03` are all different types of the third or moment.

- `m03` is the third order moment
- `mu03` is the third order central moment, i.e. the same as `m03` but if the blob was centered around (0, 0)
- `nu03` is mean-shifted and normalized, i.e. the same as `mu03` but divided by an area.

Let's say you wanted to *describe* a shape but be agnostic to the size or the location of it in your image. Then you would use the mean-shifted and normalized descriptors, `nu03`. But if you wanted to keep the size as part of the description, then you'd use `mu03`. If you wanted to keep the location information as well, you'd use `m03`.

You can think about it in the same way as you think about distributions in general. Saying that I have a sample of `x = 500` in a normal distribution with mean 450 and standard deviation 25 is basically the same thing as saying I have a sample of `x = 2` in a normal distribution with mean 0 and std dev 1. Sometimes you might want to talk about the distribution in terms of it's actual parameters (mean 450, std dev 25), sometimes you might want to talk about the distribution as if it's mean centered (mean 0, std dev 25), and sometimes talk about it as if it's the standard Gaussian (mean 0, std dev 1).

[This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034261/5087436) goes over how to manually calculate the moments, which in tandem with the 'basic' descriptions I gave above, should make the formulas in the OpenCV docs for `moments()` a little more comfortable.